# Instantiate a class from a string

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

In dart is it possible to instantiate a class from a string?

For example:

- vanilla in javascript:

```js
var myObject = window[classNameString];
```

- Objective-C:

```objectice-c
id myclass = [[NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know the library name and class name to make things work properly.  Assume you know both, the below example will instantiate the `TestClass` and call `doStuff` on it.

```dart
library test;

import "dart:mirrors";

class TestClass {
  doStuff() => print("doStuff was called!");
}

main() {
  MirrorSystem mirrors = currentMirrorSystem();
  LibraryMirror lm = mirrors.libraries['test'];
  ClassMirror cm = lm.classes['TestClass'];
  Future tcFuture = cm.newInstance('', []);
  tcFuture.then((InstanceMirror im) {
    var tc = im.reflectee;
    tc.doStuff();
  });
}
```

A few notes about this solution:

1. The library `test` we are trying to load the class from is already imported in the VM, which makes this case a bit easier.
2. the call the `newInstance` allows for passing parameters to the constructor.  Positional arguments are implemented, but named parameters are not yet implemented (as of the M2 release).
3. `newInstance` returns a [Future](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_async/Future.html) to allow it to work across [isolates](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_isolate.html).

Comment: `newInstance` doesn't return a `Future` because instantiating the class may require an async operation, that's not true, everything is already loaded. It returns a `Future` because the Mirrors API is intentionally asynchronous, as it will work across isolates in the future (and cross-isolate communication is always asynchronous). If you carefully inspect the `newInstance` invocation (and others like `get/setField` or `invoke` too), you will note that under the hood, it works synchronously. That might obviously change in the future.

Comment: Note: this might not work when compiled to JavaScript. The dart2js compiler doesn't yet fully support mirrors.

Comment: uh .. this makes Dart look less dynamic than Java .. reflection is a very important feature ..

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
Map models = {"Player": Player.instantiate};
var player = models["Player"]();

class Player{
  static instantiate() => Player();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax has changed.
I got it working this way

```dart
library test;

import "dart:mirrors";

class TestClass {
  doStuff() => print("doStuff was called!");
}

main() {
  MirrorSystem mirrors = currentMirrorSystem();
  LibraryMirror lm = mirrors.libraries.values.firstWhere(
      (LibraryMirror lm) => lm.qualifiedName == new Symbol('test'));

  ClassMirror cm = lm.declarations[new Symbol('TestClass')];

  InstanceMirror im = cm.newInstance(new Symbol(''), []);
  var tc = im.reflectee;
  tc.doStuff();
}
```

If there are more libraries named 'test' this will fail though.

Comment: Indeed, `classes` getter has been changed to `declarations`.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue that has plagued me until I figured that I could implement a crude **from** method to handle the conversion of *encoded Json Objects/strings* or *Dart Maps* to the desired class.

Below is a simple example that also handles nulls and accepts JSON (*as the* **string** *parameter*)

```
import 'dart:convert';

class PaymentDetail
{
  String AccountNumber;
  double Amount;
  int ChargeTypeID;
  String CustomerNames;

  PaymentDetail({
    this.AccountNumber,
    this.Amount,
    this.ChargeTypeID,
    this.CustomerNames
  });

  PaymentDetail from ({ string : String, object : Map  }) {
     var map   = (object==null) ? (string==null) ? Map() : json.decode(string) : (object==null) ? Map() : object;
     return new PaymentDetail(
        AccountNumber             : map["AccountNumber"] as String,
        Amount                    : map["Amount"] as double,
        ChargeTypeID              : map["ChargeTypeID"] as int,
        CustomerNames             : map["CustomerNames"] as String
     );
  }

}
```

Below is it's implementation

```
 PaymentDetail payDetail =  new PaymentDetail().from(object: new Map());

 PaymentDetail otherPayDetail =  new PaymentDetail().from(object: {"AccountNumber": "1234", "Amount": 567.2980908});
```

Once again, this is simplistic and tedious to clone throughout the project but it works for simple cases.