# How to get a Class name dynamically (from a string) in Dart, then create an instance?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```dart
class MyClass() {...}

var class_name = "MyClass"; // user input here
new class_name();           // so here, class_name is supposed to be a class constant
```

Can anybody suggest a simple way to do it?

Comment: This question was asked one day ago...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiate a class from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242712/instantiate-a-class-from-a-string)

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but the answer won't work anymore. Too many changes since January.

Comment: How about updating the old question instead of creating a new one? So other user don't try to use the non working awnser?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it, is:

```dart
library my_library;

import 'dart:mirrors';

void main() {
  var userInput = 'MyClass';
  var symbol = new Symbol(userInput);
  var myClasses = currentMirrorSystem().findLibrary(#my_library).declarations.values.where((dm) => dm is ClassMirror);
  var cm = myClasses.firstWhere((cm) => cm.simpleName == symbol);
  var instance = cm.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []).reflectee;
}

class MyClass {}
```

If you compile to JS, you should also look into using `@MirrorsUsed` otherwise the size of the generated JS will be quite large.