# Create an instance of an Generic Class from a String in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Hello from here I know that I can create an instance from a String:

[How to get a Class name dynamically (from a string) in Dart, then create an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023087/how-to-get-a-class-name-dynamically-from-a-string-in-dart-then-create-an-inst)

but How do I create an instance of a Generic class from a String, ie:

```
var class_name = "GenericController<Book>"; // user input here
new class_name();
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way. `newInstance` doesn't allow to pass type arguments. (here is another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166146)

Comment: This would have been the better replacement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112130

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible (as you probably noticed). There's an open case in the Dart issue tracker you should Star to show your interest:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12921