# Dart - class exists from string - class instance from string

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I was wondering if it is possible to find out whether a class (in the same library) exists by name (String) and also if it is possible to create an instance of a class from a name (String).

In PHP you can do it like:

```
$className = 'SomeClass';
if (class_exists($className))
    $instance = new $className;
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242712/instantiate-a-class-from-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it more like

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class SomeClass {}

main() {
  String className = 'SomeClass';
  var instance;

  ClassMirror cm = currentMirrorSystem().isolate.rootLibrary.declarations[
      new Symbol(className)];
  if (cm != null) {
    instance = cm.newInstance(new Symbol(''), []).reflectee;
  }
  print(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In time of posting this answer, the solution is not as straightforward as in PHP, but it can be managed this way:

```
String className = 'SomeClass';
if (currentMirrorSystem().isolate.rootLibrary.declarations.keys.join('').contains('Symbol("${className}")'))
    var instance = currentMirrorSystem().isolate.rootLibrary.declarations[new Symbol(className)].newInstance(new Symbol(''), []).reflectee;
```

It's a little bit naughty approach with searching in a string, but it's the simplest way I could make it working by myself.

Next you can call the instance's properties simply:

```
instance.method();
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: My code inspector also keeps warning me: "The method 'newInstance' is not defined for the class 'DeclarationMirror'", but the code works as expected anyway.