# Loading All Classes in a library - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to add a config file written in yaml, whereby I define all routes and their handlers.

I am using [Fluro](https://github.com/theyakka/fluro) and yaml libraries, now I am looking for a way to either:

- load all classes in a specific path
- load all classes in a specific library
- load a class by String path or name

The only ways I found involve `dart:mirrors` which is not supported in Flutter, for example : [Instantiate a class from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242712/instantiate-a-class-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

```
https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen
```

or

```
https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable
```

which both use code generation.

With `source_gen` you basically just generate the code yourself.
With `reflectable` you get reflection-like features that are then realized by code generated based on the features you are using.