# How to create a class(page) from a string in Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to redirect the user to the desired page depending on the "navigation" key, I tried in such ways:

```
final _bottomAppBarItem = [
{
  'iconData': Icons.airplay,
  'text': 'news',
  'navigation': NewsPage(),
},
{
  'iconData': Icons.person,
  'text': 'profile',
  'navigation': UserProfilePage(),
}];

Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => item['navigation']));
```

OR

```
final _bottomAppBarItem = [
{
  'iconData': Icons.airplay,
  'text': 'news',
  'navigation': 'NewsPage',
},
{
  'iconData': Icons.person,
  'text': 'profile',
  'navigation': 'UserProfilePage',
}];

Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => item['navigation']()));
```

But in both cases it turns out a mistake, how can I live with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use named routing as decribed in [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes). You can parameterize your route with custom strings.

A simple use case of named route:

```
onPressed: () {
  // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
}
```

Another solution, which is overhead for this situation, is to use [mirrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242712/instantiate-a-class-from-a-string).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I think this is really the best option. My way the first option turns out to work, but for its normal operation you need to add 'import' for each page

Comment: Do you mean that you have to import material library to every page?